# How can I create a connection between drawn lines in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a problem with implementing the newest version of leaflet draw to my project.

The only requirement is to only use a CSS & Script links to get the plugin to work...(If it's not possible just ignore and try another way)

Basically, it should work just as on their website - https://freedraw.herokuapp.com/

What should I do to load the newest version of the plugin? What am I doing wrong?

I'm a beginner in this so thanks for any help.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Free Draw</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div >

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" >
</script >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.js"> </script >
```

```js
<script>
//Creating map and setting zoom
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.8650, -75.2094], 3);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
    ext: 'png',
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Wikimedia maps | Map data &copy; <a target="_blank" href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OSM contributors</a>'
}).addTo(this.map);

// Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
edit: {
featureGroup: drawnItems
}
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
var type = e.layerType,
layer = e.layer;
if (type === 'marker') {
layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
}
drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

</script >
```

```html
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is 1.0.4 - so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css" />
```

and

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"> </script >
```

should fetch it in for you.